# Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, http, activerecord

I want create new method by post data to rails server and create action to save data to database. I post data correctly and data save to database correct. But at end I get `500 internal error`. I show `create` action:

```
class Api::V1::BolouksController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def create
    @bolouk = Bolouk.create(bolouk_params)
    @bolouk.save
    respond_with(@bolouk)
  end
  private
  def bolouk_params
    params.require(:bolouk).permit(:boloukcode, :north, :south, :east, :west)
  end
end
```

And server log:

```
Started POST "/api/bolouks.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-31 12:36:10 +0430
Processing by Api::V1::BolouksController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"south"=>"76876", "west"=>"46365", "east"=>"987987", "north"=>"897987", "boloukcode"=>"21321", "bolouk"=>{"boloukcode"=>"21321", "north"=>"89798
7", "south"=>"76876", "east"=>"987987", "west"=>"46365"}}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "bolouks" ("boloukcode", "created_at", "east", "north", "south", "updated_at", "west") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["boloukcode",
 "21321"], ["created_at", "2014-08-31 08:06:10.645999"], ["east", "987987"], ["north", "897987"], ["south", "76876"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-31 08:06:10.64599
9"], ["west", "46365"]]
   (96.6ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 162ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 96.6ms)
```

I don't know the problem, because when I remove all method of `create` action, I again get `500 Internal Error`.

```
class Api::V1::BolouksController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def create
  end
end
```

`server log`:

```
Started POST "/api/bolouks.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-31 12:40:48 +0430
Processing by Api::V1::BolouksController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"south"=>"543543", "west"=>"76875", "east"=>"4312432", "north"=>"987967", "boloukcode"=>"68987", "bolouk"=>{"boloukcode"=>"68987", "north"=>"987
967", "south"=>"543543", "east"=>"4312432", "west"=>"76875"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I cannot understand the problem. Where is the problem? How can I fix `500 Internal Error`?
Update question:

I post data from angularjs code, I add angular controller and service below:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('BoloukCtrl', ['$scope','Session', 'Bolouks', 'Secure', function($scope, Session, Bolouks, Secure){
    $scope.bolouk = {};
    $scope.bolouk.boloukcode  = $scope.bolouk.north = $scope.bolouk.east  = $scope.bolouk.west  = $scope.bolouk.south = "";

    $scope.save = function(){
        var alaki = Bolouks.create($scope.bolouk);
        $scope.bolouk = {};
        $scope.bolouk.boloukcode  = $scope.bolouk.north = $scope.bolouk.east  = $scope.bolouk.west  = $scope.bolouk.south = "";
    }
}]);
```

`boloukService.js`:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('boloukService', ['ngResource']);
app.factory('Bolouks', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/bolouks.json', {}, {
        index: { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    });
});
```

`view.html`:

```
<form ng-submit="save()" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        //I complete bolouk field and then post to angularjs controller and by using service, post to rails server.
</form>
```

Comment: can you post views structure of your app?

Comment: try putting ` respond_to :json, :html` for example at the beginning of your controller class and make sure you have corosponding response template

Comment: you probably just need ` respond_to :json` since it's an API

Comment: @Nimir I use `respond_to :json`, but I get `500 Internal Error`.

Comment: are you handling the period in your url correctly?

Comment: @RoyTheBoy I don't have any knowlege about url period.

Comment: you don't need it to respond to json, I don't use one but I think it has to be handled. Try this link http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/06/18/rails-3-resource-routes-with-dots-or-how-to-make-a-ruby-developer-go-a-little-bit-insane/